# Git repos on new hard drive

Tags: git

my old drive died and we moved to a new one.

I thought my Git repos were all fine, but then I realized that only the repos in my "Webapps" folder are operating, and that those I created in my Customers directory aren't.

Which caused me to then realize that the Customers folder was not present when I installed Git, while the Webapps folder was.

(This is Win Vista).

Is there a command I need to run?

Comment: I would like, when I issue a command such as "git branch" to not see the error "fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git"

These were working repos before I copied them to the new drive.

Comment: If you get that error the error message is quite descriptive and should be quite obvious what you need to do - `git init` or copy the .git folders _which are missing_ from your old drive.

Comment: AD7six, besides the video I'm editing and the 10 email threads I'm in, there are some 25 tabs open on my browser at the moment, from the current versions of Ohio SB 315 (Education) to Railscast #348 to a blog on competency-based learning and a CMU-based robotics simulator for teens, plus my actual paying customers. IF it were QUITE obvious that the git files somehow didn't get copied with the 8,540 files and folders which did get copied, do ya think I'd have taken more of my time to ask?

Comment: AD7six, it's not. I just thought I'd try to save the next guy who needs a little help from downvotes and your tongue.

Comment: A tip for avoiding downvotes: If you get an error message when you do something **read it** . If you don't know what it means - **include it in the question**. I stand by the statement that getting "you're not in a git repo" as an error message is pretty obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that the .git folders were missing. The issue had nothing to do with when the folder was copied, but how.

The various folders in which git worked fine were pushed from the old drive to the new via Windows Explorer; the .git files got pushed with them.

The offending folders, however, were pulled off the old drive onto the new, via DOS Xcopy, I think, which skipped the .git folders.

Thanks.